# Heroku, data import error with mysql2

Tags: heroku, mysql2, dbimport

I am beginner on Heroku.
I push my exist ruby on rails application into heroku and that was fine.
Next i push my mysql data into heroku with 'push' command as following.

```
$heroku config:add DATABASE_URL='mysql2://<my CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL>@<myapp>.herokuapp.com/heroku_db?reconnect=true'
$heroku db:push mysql2://<my CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL>@<myapp>.herokuapp.com/<my dump file>
```

But i got error as following.

```
Failed to connect to database:
Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError -> Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on '<myapp>.herokuapp.com' (110)
```

I am confusing what should i do.
Someone tell me how to resolve it.

Many thanks.

-Ono

Comment: I notice that heroku ignite provided 'mysql://' not 'mysql2://' on CLEARDAB_DATABASE_URL. And my app was using 'mysql2://'. Dose ignite not provide 'mysql2://'?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `db:push` or `db:pull`. Please export a sql file locally and either pipe it in like so:

```
$ heroku pg:psql DATABASE_URL -a app_name < file.sql
```

Or better, use Postgres locally and use pgbackups to import/export like so: [Importing and Exporting Heroku Postgres Databases with PG Backups](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export)